# Error updating SQS attributes When Apply Terraform First Time

Tags: terraform

every time I run my terraform it will fail at first time, but success after retry.

terraform give me below errors:

```
1 error occurred:
    * module.my_module.aws_sqs_queue_policy.aws_sqs_queue_policy: 1 error occurred:
    * aws_sqs_queue_policy.aws_sqs_queue_policy: Error updating SQS attributes: InvalidAttributeValue: Invalid value for the parameter Policy.
    status code: 400, request id:
```

below is my terraform script:
I want to create a sqs with a consumer role on it. so consumer could assume this consumer role to read messages from sqs.

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "consumer_queue" {
  name                       = "my-queue" 
}

# Allow the consumer to assume the consumer role
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "queue_consumer_role_permissions_doc" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${var.consumer_arn}"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "queue_consumer_role" {
  name               = "queue-consumer-role"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.queue_consumer_role_permissions_doc.json}"

}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "zo_message_bus_queue_permissions" {

  //All consumer to read from this queue
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${aws_iam_role.queue_consumer_role.arn}"]
    }

    actions = [
      "SQS:ReceiveMessage"]

    resources = ["${aws_sqs_queue.consumer_queue.arn}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "aws_sqs_queue_policy" {
  depends_on = ["aws_sqs_queue.consumer_queue"]
  queue_url  = "${aws_sqs_queue.consumer_queue.id}"
  policy     = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.zo_message_bus_queue_permissions.json}"
}
```

Comment: What does the plan show on the second apply?

Comment: update sqs redrive_policy and create aws_sqs_queue_policy

Comment: Update your question to show the full plan please